# How in linq to entities, many to many add reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a many to many relation for google drive where folder can have many parent folders and files and folders inside. How do i insert in my db item properly where parent folder already exists, here i get duplicate value error. Im using FE 6.0v.

```
       var gDoc = new GoogleDoc();
       ///

       do some entity stuff

       ///

       foreach (ParentReference parent in input.Parents)
       {
          var gParent = new GoogleParent();
          ///
          do some entity stuff
          ///
          gDoc.GoogleParents.Add(gParent);

       }

       using (Model2Container dBase = new Model2Container())
       {
            dBase.GoogleDocs.Add(gDoc);
            dBase.SaveChanges();
       }
```

EDIT, added some code

added this before alocating a new parrent of i would get an error. AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.

```
       GoogleParent gParent = OAuthDBGoogleDrive.getParent(parent.Id);
       if (gParent != null)
            gDoc.GoogleParents.Add(gParent);
```

added this when im saving to the db

```
      dBase.GoogleDocs.Add(gDoc);
      foreach (GoogleParent parent in gDoc.GoogleParents)
      {
          GoogleParent gparent = dBase.GoogleParents.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == parent.Id);
          if (gparent != null)
             dBase.Entry(gparent).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
     }
     dBase.SaveChanges();
```

Still getting duplicate error

EDIT 2: this seems to work

```
       using (Model2Container dBase = new Model2Container())
       {
       var gDoc = new GoogleDoc();
       ///

       do some entity stuff

       ///

       foreach (ParentReference parent in input.Parents)
       {
                GoogleParent gParent = OAuthDBGoogleDrive.getParent(parent.Id);
                if (gParent != null)
                {
                    gDoc.GoogleParents.Add(gParent);
                    dBase.GoogleParents.Attach(gParent);
                }
                else
                {
                    gParent = new GoogleParent();
                    ///
                    do some entity stuff
                    ///
                    gDoc.GoogleParents.Add(gParent);
                }
       }   

       dBase.GoogleDocs.Add(gDoc);
       dBase.SaveChanges();
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you `DbSet.Attach()` entities that already exist in the database, and `DbSet.Add()` entities that do not exist in the database. Both of these functions will attach entities to the context in the `Unchanged` or `Added` state respectively. All entities in the object graph are also added in this state if they are not already tracked by the context.

As a result you may have need to change the tracked state of a single entity if it is being tracked in an incorrect state. This can be done as follows:

```
// eg give the entity the unchanged state
context.Entry(myEntity).State == EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Comment: i know that but GoogleParents is a list and only has add. Attach i can only use directly on the database. I dont know how to set attach or unchanged on an object thats part of an object because there stored in a list.

Comment: @sinofis, you're adding a new document that holds a reference to an existing entity. You must make sure your existing entities are being tracked by the context in the proper state ie `Unchanged`.

Comment: well i coudnt add new parent or change state of a new parent if there was a copy if it in the database or i would get that error. And the way im doing it doesnt seem to change its state

Comment: Look closely at what your second code snippet edit does. It loops through googleparents that are already added to the context (via gDoc) and tries to pull _another instance_ of that parent from the db and attach it to the context.

Comment: noticed that, but if changed it i would get  AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges. Not the pritiest but i found something that worked